# colorgcc perl script with output to non-tty enabled writing to C dependency files

Tags: perl

Ok, so here's my issue.  I have written a build script in bash that pipes output to tee and sorts different output to different log files (so I can summarize errors/warnings at the end and get some statistics on files built).  I wanted to use the colorgcc perl script (colorgcc.1.3.2) to colorize the output from gcc and had found in other places that this won't work piping to tee, since the script checks if it is writing to something that is not a tty.  Having disabled this check everything was working until I did a full build and discovered some of the code we receive from another group builds C dependency files (we don't control this code, changing it or the build process for these isn't really an option).

The problem is that these .d files have the form as follows:
    `filename.o filename.d : filename.c \

        dependant_file1.h \

        dependant_file2.h (and so on for however many dependencies there are)`

This output from GCC gets written into the .d file, but, since it is close enough to a warning/error message colorgcc outputs color codes (believe it's the check for `filename:lineno:message` but not 100% sure, could be `filename:message` check in the `GCCOUT` while loop).  I've tried editing the regex to attempt to not match this but my perl-fu is admittedly pretty weak.  So what I end up with is a color code on each line for these dependency files, which obviously causes the build to fail.

I ended up just replacing the check for `! -t STDOUT` with a check for a NO_COLOR envar I set and unset in the build script for these directories (emulates the previous behavior of no color for non-tty).  This works great if I run the full script, but doesn't if I cd into the directory and just run make (obviously setting and unsetting manually would work but this is a pain to do every time).  Anyone have any ideas how to prevent this script from writing color codes into dependency files?

Comment: Let me try a summary: You use a script to colorize output, hacked it to generate color-codes for file-output (which it does not normally) and now want to get rid of the color codes? Simple answer: Remove your hacks.

Comment: Please stop adding C tag. This is not related to C, but your build system. There are no "C dependency files".

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I worked around this.  I added the following to colorgcc to search the gcc input for the flag to generate the .d files and just directly called the compiler in that case. This was inserted in place of the original TTY check.

`for each $argnum (0 .. $#ARGV)
    {
        if ($ARGV[$argnum] =~ m/-M{1,2}/)
        {
            exec $compiler, @ARGV
                or die("Couldn't exec");
        }
    }`

I don't know if this is the proper 'perl' way of doing this sort of operation but it seems to work.  Compiling inside directories that build .d files no longer inserts color codes and the source file builds do (both to terminal and my log files like I wanted).  I guess sometimes the answer is more hacks instead of "hey, did you try giving up?".